# Laravel relationship error in migration

Tags: laravel-5, foreign-keys, migration

I am trying to make two tables relationship in laravel. But i can't understand why i'm getting error "errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"". please check my migration code below.

items table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->decimal('price',5,2);
        $table->integer('count_left')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    });
}
```

categories

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: can you add delete method too ? `$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');`

Comment: Hi, still getting same error

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have fix this error after rename migration file "Categories: 2018_02_22_154940_create_categories_table" "Items 2018_02_23_154957_create_items_table"